# How to isolate letter from variable into its own variable, stopping at the words length?

Tags: javascript, html

I love computers and have recently made the jump from picture based programming to Javascript, and am trying to make Hangman!

At the moment, I have made an array with all the words that can be placed in, and I have made a function to pick a word randomly out of the list.

If the current word to be guessed was the variable currentWord, how would I isolate each of the letters in current word into its own variable (letter_?), where I could then change the colour to be the colour of the background (hide the letter until it was guessed correctly). Here is the code which I have made so far...

```
//Framework for choosing word
var currentWord = word[Math.floor(Math.random()*word.length)];
//Debug for current word (EG Displays the current word
document.write('Current word: ' + currentWord + '<br>' + '<br>');
var letter_1 = (currentWord.charAt(0));
document.write(letter_1);
```

As you can see, i have been able to isolate the first letter of currentWord using `currentWord.charAt(0)` and placing it into the variable `letter_1`, but I want to be able to create the variables as I go along in a loop. For example, for the word car there would be the variables `letter_1, Letter_2, Letter_3` because there are  3 letters in the word. However, what if I had Mountain Dew? There would be 11 (12 including the space), therefore I would need to make the variables for the letters uniquely for each word.

Is there any way to do this? (I think it might have something to do with a loop!)

Thanks so so much for helping out a noob!

Hamish

Comment: what is picture based programming?

Comment: Aye, its a language like scratch or tynker... think of dragging and dropping lines of code which are little boxes. Check out https://scratch.mit.edu/ if you want to know more!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`currentWord.split('');` will produce an array of all of the letters making up your word

```js
var currentWord = "hello world";
var split = currentWord.split('');
alert(JSON.stringify(split));
```

Comment: Alright, I'll have a crack at it now! Thanks for your quick reply :D

Comment: No problem, I added an executable example for you to see the output

Comment: Ok, so how would call each of the letters in the array? EDIT: just reloaded the page, thanks for the executable!

Comment: Ok, so I just had a crack at implementing your code into my HTML page, but sadly it doesnt alert me with the new array. does the JSON.stringify work in HTML?

Comment: @Mish_00—no, *split* is an ECMAScript (aka javascript) method, nothing to do with HTML. You could do `document.write(word.split('').join('<br>'))` within a script element.

Comment: Perfect! That was super helpful! Thanks so so much!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code for splitting the word into spaces! 
`document.write(currentWord.split('').join(' '))`